# Where to place the Y axis label

Tags: labels, readability, charts

I would like to improve the readability of the label on charts.

At the moment there look like this

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcf2ND.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

What is the best placement and orientation for chart label that offers a good readability and avoids wasting too much space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative for the Y axis label suggested by [statistician Naomi Robbins](http://www.forbes.com/sites/naomirobbins/2013/02/12/how-to-position-y-axis-labels-in-graphs/) is to place the label *above* the Y axis. This has the advantage of not having to read the vertical text and does not waste as much space. See the example in the top right chart.

[image]

IMO the non-centered X axis in your mock up looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's pretty standard to place an axis label **centered** with respect to the corresponding axis.
[image]

So, your chart's Y axis label looks fine to me, but the X axis label should be centered, in my opinion.

Comment: thank you for your reply but the vertical text bother me because it is difficult to read. I am looking a different solution.

Comment: @Renaud: You're welcome! I can think of several **alternatives** to vertical text, including *call-out*, sometimes referred to as *annotation*, for each line (placed inside the chart area) or color-coded lines with *legend* to the right of the chart.